# Redux state does not update even when reducer called with correct data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

For some reason, even though the reducer runs and console.log shows that the correct data was passed to it, the redux store was not updated.

Relevant files:

1. App.jsx

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store()}>
```

2. Store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = (initialState = {}) =>{
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
}
export default store;
```

3. Register.tsx

```
...
<Pressable 
style={styles.button}
onPress={() => this.props.submitRegistration(this.state)}
>
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    submitRegistration: (data: any) => {
      dispatch(UserActions.submitRegister(data))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

4. UserActions

```
import { signUp } from '../../services/backend';
import { setUser } from '../../actions';

export function submitRegister(data: any) {
  return async (dispatch: any) => {
    const response = await signUp(data);

    const responseData = await response.json();
    if(responseData.token) {
      console.log('here', responseData);
      dispatch(setUser(responseData.user));
    }
  }; 
}
```

5. Action creator

```
export const setUser = (user: any) => ({
  type: 'SET_USER',
  user
});
```

6. User Reducer

```
import { SET_USER } from "../actions/actionTypes"

const initialState = {
  user: {}
}

const User = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_USER: 
      console.log('here action', action.user);
      return { user: action.user}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
export default User;
```

I would really appreciate any help possible. Seems like I misconfigured in someway because even when I set initial state :

```
const initialState = {
  user: {firstName: "John"}
}
```

it's not reflected in the redux store.

Answer (score 0):

In your action creator:

export const setUser = (user: any) => (
return {
type: 'SET_USER',
user
});

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :( I've modified the action creator to be:

export function setUser(user:any) {
    return { type: 'SET_USER', user }
}

Comment: Also want to clarify the console(here action) in the reducer did run, so the reducer ran. But the state wasn't updated